# Change the width of a formattable table in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following Shiny Application:

```
library(shiny)


list1 <- c(0.2,0.8,0.5)
list2 <- c("element1", "element2", "element3")
df <- data.frame(list1, list2)

UI <- fluidPage(
  formattableOutput("table1")
)
Server <- function(input, output) {

  output$table1 <- renderFormattable({
    formattable(df, list(
      list1 = color_tile("green", "red") 
    ))
  })

}


shinyApp(ui = UI, server = Server)
```

This works fine. However, I am looking for a way to set the column widths. I might be overlooking it in the documentation but I cant find a way to adjust the widths.

Any feedback on how I should change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shiny renders it's code into HTML, so you can actually use CSS to adjust any aesthetic you'd like to change post render. Here's an easy fix using CSS.

First create a directory, `www` in the app directory, and create a file called `styles.css` which will serve as your CSS file. Add the following lines to `styles.css`:

```
table {
  width: 400px !important;
}
```

This adjusts the width of all tables displayed in your app to be 400px, you can change this value as needed. Next, add `includeCSS("www/styles.css")` to the UI portion of your app like so:

```
library(shiny)


list1 <- c(0.2,0.8,0.5)
list2 <- c("element1", "element2", "element3")
df <- data.frame(list1, list2)

UI <- fluidPage(
  includeCSS("www/styles.css"),
  formattableOutput("table1")
)
Server <- function(input, output) {

  output$table1 <- renderFormattable({
    formattable(df, list(
      list1 = color_tile("green", "red") 
    ))
  })

}


shinyApp(ui = UI, server = Server)
```

This will let Shiny know to use the CSS in the file we just created when rendering the page.